# How to detect Orientation Change in Custom Keyboard Extension in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, uiinputviewcontroller

In Custom Keyboard Extension , we can't use

```
`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`
```

and `sharedApplication`.

I need to detect portrait or landscape in keyboard when rotate.

How can i detect when orientation change in Custom Keyboard extension?

Comment: I encourage you to change your accepted answer. As the current solution does not work for iPads.

Comment: Why? For iPad you can change view frame size width to 768 for Portrait. For Landscape you can do it with if else.

Comment: Does not support future device sizes though. You would have to update your app. I believe I read something about Apple coming out with two new iPhone screen sizes. http://www.macrumors.com/roundup/iphone-6/

Comment: Yes. When they release devices with new size , we can detect View.frame.size.width or height for each devices.

Comment: But you would have to update your app just for this reason? Why not have it all detected from the start? Plus then you end up with multiple conditional statements instead of just one.

Comment: The other problem with the currently accepted solution is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called twice upon an orientation change. We only want the method to be called ONCE per orientation change. And with the current method, the second time it is called (which is the time that the proper orientation is finally detectable), the orientation animation has already completed and your keyboard stretch will appear laggy.

Comment: Added best solution working on all screen sizes and using strictly non-deprecated methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25222353/2057171

Comment: I once more urge you to change your accepted answer, the currently accepted answer will not work on iPhone6 and iPhone6+ and anyone who used that code will have to update their apps because of this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In order to update your custom keyboard when the orientation changes, override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in the `UIInputViewController`. As far as I can tell, when a rotation occurs this method is always called.

Additionally, as the traditional `[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` doesn't work, to determine the current orientation use the following snippet:

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height){
    //Keyboard is in Portrait
}
else{
    //Keyboard is in Landscape
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: viewDidlayoutSubviews is NOT called when rotate to Landscape

Comment: @iAn It's working in my app when rotate to Landscape.

Comment: @Sabo you should mark this as the answered response. works on my end

Comment: Magic numbers... oh the horror. Don't do this!

Comment: @Joey Here is my non-deprecated method without `magic numbers`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25222353/2057171

Comment: Use - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration instead

Comment: surprisingly even for iPhone 6 plus the width of keyboard is still 320!

Comment: @EthanLong Just checked on iPhone6+ simulator, it returned width value of 414.00 ... NSLog: `WIDTH IS: 414.000000`

Comment: @Albert Renshaw, maybe it's because I did not provide splash screen for iPhone 6 and plus? I always get 320 from the simulators

Comment: @EthanLong Strange, I didn't either, new project, are you running the script in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw not sure about extensions, last time I checked (beta 6?) it was all 320. But for app's if you don't provide large launch screens it must be 320.

Comment: @EthanLong I provided NO launch screen and ran it on the actual live iOS8 version and it returned 414 on iPhone 6 PLUS (Are you sure you ran the plus?)

Comment: I have the same but how to get device is landScapeLeft or landScapeRight like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462091/get-device-current-orientation-app-extension

Comment: On iPad, inside viewDidLayoutSubviews, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] has the old values before orientation change:/

Comment: Works for me. Currently using it in my app.

Answer (score 26):

Non-deprecated and will work on any device screen size (including future screen sizes [Apple will be releasing this year](http://www.macrumors.com/roundup/iphone-6/)).

In CustomKeyboard `ViewController.m`:

```objectivec
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    NSLog(@"%@", (self.view.frame.size.width == ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width*([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width<[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height))+([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height*([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width>[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height))) ? @"Portrait" : @"Landscape");
}
```

done.

---

Or... for a more easy to read version of this code:

```objectivec
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    
    int appExtensionWidth = (int)round(self.view.frame.size.width);
    
    int possibleScreenWidthValue1 = (int)round([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
    int possibleScreenWidthValue2 = (int)round([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    
    int screenWidthValue;
    
    if (possibleScreenWidthValue1 < possibleScreenWidthValue2) {
        screenWidthValue = possibleScreenWidthValue1;
    } else {
        screenWidthValue = possibleScreenWidthValue2;
    }
    
    if (appExtensionWidth == screenWidthValue) {
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"landscape");
    }
}
```

Comment: On iPhone 6 simulator, it prints out `Landscape` even though the device is in portrait mode.

Comment: @SalavatKhanov Works fine for me in iPhone6 simulator. Which xCode BETA are you running?

Comment: This breaks down with apps not built for iphone 6 and phone 6+ dimensions. For instance, I'm testing whatsapp now and it reports the self.view.frame to be (0, 0, 320, 216) and the screen size is (414, 736) so it throws this logic off.

Comment: @fatshu The logic still works just fine? It's just the numbers are off haha

Comment: I have the same but how to get device is landScapeLeft or landScapeRight like this one please if possible then check this and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462091/get-device-current-orientation-app-extension

Comment: oh dear this is so hacky, apple need to get on their damn game

Comment: @foreyez Not hacky :) It is very easy to follow logic. Assuming new screen sizes that come out will always have the longer side being the vertical side (If they dont then they are in landscape by default so this code still works). If height is shortest is becomes the "horizontal side" (shortest side in portrait), if width is shortest it becomes the "horizontal side" (shortest side in portrait). We get the width of the app extension (keyboards always span the width of the screen (portrait). If the horizontal side is equal to keyboard width its portrait, else landscape.

Comment: that might be true, but I noticed viewDidLayoutSubviews gets called multiple times, after you change to landscape (from portrait). AND it gives multiple heights for the new widths (both heights given are smaller than the new landscape width) so I don't know which height to use. I don't know why it's so hard for apple to just give us some callback that happens ONCE and says what the old width/height was, what the new width/height is, and the orientation. it's not rocket science. you have thousands of developers working on creating things, why can't they provide the most basic information.

Comment: @foreyez Hahahaha Yeah I don't know what they were thinking on that one. But the multiple sizes returned is why the logic code above is used :D

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way, just looking at the screen width:

```
 double width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
 double interfaceWidth = MIN([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

 BOOL isPortrait = (width == interfaceWidth) ? YES : NO;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just see if width < height?  e.g.: `CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;  BOOL isPortrait = screenSize.width < screenSize.height;`

Answer (score 3):

use `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:`
inside your viewController

Comment: The method doesn’t seem to be called when the controller is running in the keyboard extension mode. Doesn’t work for me on the Simulator nor the actual device, as of iOS 8 Beta 5. Does it work for you? I’d love it to work, it looks like the correct, future-proof solution.

Comment: To be honest I didn't test it before posting, You are right, it doesn't work, as a alternate way you can use viewDidLayoutSubviews which called a little bit later, but hope in future it will work as it works for normal UIViewControllers.

Comment: My Radar issue was marked as a duplicate of 17472132, which is currently still open. Hopefully that means this solution will eventually work.

Comment: As of iOS 8.3 beta 2, `viewWillTransitionToSize` is finally getting called during orientation changes. On the other hand the old workaround in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` stopped working for me, since the reported view size is wrong. Let’s hope we won’t have to handle the rotation according to specific iOS versions… (The Radar issue is still open.)

Comment: I believe this is now the accepted method to be using. It is working in my app and i'm using it to trigger re-layout of a programmatic text view when the orientation changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    if (self.view.frame.size.width == 0 || self.view.frame.size.height == 0)
        return;

    [self.inputView removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat screenH = screenSize.height;
    CGFloat screenW = screenSize.width;
    BOOL isLandscape =  !(self.view.frame.size.width ==
                      (screenW*(screenW<screenH))+(screenH*(screenW>screenH)));
    NSLog(isLandscape ? @"Screen: Landscape" : @"Screen: Potriaint");
    self.isLandscape = isLandscape;
    if (isLandscape) {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.landscapeHeight;
        [self.inputView addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
    } else {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.portraitHeight;
        [self.inputView addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
    }

    //trigger default first view
    [btn_gif sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` can be used, I just tried this on my iPad running a keyboard on iOS 8.1. Note that those are deprecated in iOS 8, but their replacement, `willTransitionToTraitCollection`, isn't called though likely because the trait collection doesn't change for the keyboard upon rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Before iOS 8.3, you have to use

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

This one does not work (it should be a bug):

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
      withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

On iOS 8.3 and later, you'd better use

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
      withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

because

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

is deprecated.

Comment: well i think viewWillTransitionToSize stilled worked before 8.3, except you had to call this function on each subview's controller, where as now you don't

Comment: Okay, I take it back, I got confused. Tried it and it's still working like before. Just to clarify, viewWillTransitionToSize gets picked up by the first view controller only, and from there you'd either have to rely on viewDidLayoutSubviews propagation or call your custom direction change functions on all the subviews. Which is probably how it was always intended to work anyway. That's how i've been using it even before 8.3 anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

In somecase [UIScreen mainscreen].bounds may not work. Sometimes it will update after viewWillTransitionToSize:

Try this

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat realScreenHeight = MAX(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
    if(size.width == realScreenHeight)
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
    else
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who are searching for the answer in **Swift 5.**

by override `func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)` method. you can detect device orientation.

here is the code for my custom keyboard.

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
        if screen.width < screen.height {
            print("!!! portrait")
            let constraintForHeight:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 325)
            constraintForHeight.isActive = true
            constraintForHeight.priority = UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh
            self.inputView?.addConstraint(constraintForHeight)
        } else {
            print("!!! landspace")
            let constraintForHeight:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 210)
            constraintForHeight.isActive = true
            constraintForHeight.priority = UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh
            self.inputView?.addConstraint(constraintForHeight)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
      - (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator 
    {   
     [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) 
        {      UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];      // do whatever 
          } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {    }];       [super viewWillTransitionToSize: size withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator]; 
 }
```

Comment: Wrong. "'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead."