# iOS Detect Today Extension Orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I'm trying to detect a Today Extension's orientation, but none of the typical methods seem to work.

I've tried the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

I've even tried using CMMotionManger.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no bullet-proof solution for Extensions.

Look at this answer for possible workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26023538/2797141

Answer (score -1):

The orientation can't be detected by any normal means. However, every time the widget  opens it calls "viewDidLoad". So, in viewDidLoad, detect screen width & height thusly and determine your own orientation.

```
int startOrientation;
int screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width; //Screen Width
int screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height; // Screen Height;

if (screenWidth > screenHeight) {
    startOrientation = @"landscape";
} else {
    startOrientation = @"portrait";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Consider the case of a container view...In that situation, width could easily be more than height while you're screen is in portrait.