# IOS 8 custom keyboard rotation handling to load another xib file for the landscape keyboard

Tags: ios, landscape-portrait, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I am looking for help on a way to handle the rotation notification from an iOS 8 device (iPhone 6) so I can load a different xib for the Landscape keyboard.

I have a few portrait keyboards, each of which loads from its xib file and all works for that, but I want to load another xib file for the landscape layout and have not found a solution that works.

I have tried registering for the notification as recommended in many other answers here but it hasn't worked.

I have tried all that is recommended here: [How to detect Orientation Change in Custom Keyboard Extension in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166878/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-custom-keyboard-extension-in-ios-8?rq=1), however determining whether we are in Landscape or Portrait by detecting the size as recommended still didn't work.

Adding some code that is used:

```
const int keyboardHeight = 375;
const int landscapekeyboardHeight = 200;


- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraintforLandscape
        = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                          toItem:nil
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                      multiplier:0.0
                                        constant:landscapekeyboardHeight];

    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraintforPortrait
        = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                          toItem:nil
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                      multiplier:0.0
                                        constant:keyboardHeight];

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
    {
        // Portrait
        [self.view removeConstraint: _heightConstraintforLandscape];
        [self.view addConstraint:  _heightConstraintforPortrait];
    }
    else
    {
        // Landscape
        [self.view removeConstraint: _heightConstraintforPortrait];
        [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraintforLandscape];     
        self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.LandscapeKeyboard;
    }
}
```

I also tried using the orientation change notification

```
// Request to turn on accelerometer and begin receiving accelerometer events
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleOrientationChangeWithNotification:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)handleOrientationChangeWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Respond to changes in device orientation
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.Keyboard;
    }
    else
    {
        self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.LandscapeKeyboard;
    }
}
```

I have tried most of the solutions proposed on Stack Overflow but nothing worked for an iOS 8 custom Keyboard.  Anyone know or seen a solution that works will be really great.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put this code in *updateViewConstraints*

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
{
    // Portrait
    [self.view removeConstraint: _heightConstraintforLandscape];
    [self.view addConstraint:  _heightConstraintforPortrait];
}
else
{
    // Landscape
    [self.view removeConstraint: _heightConstraintforPortrait];
    [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraintforLandscape];     
    self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.LandscapeKeyboard;
}
```

Instead move it to *viewDidLayoutSubviews* which is called whenever the device rotates.

Comment: this method is called multiple times, when the orientation is being changed!